# How to hide a column on REACT Material table in all rows and show it on Edit for the Particular Row I am editing and Add Operations on new row adding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am working with React Material Table. Please assist I need to hide a **Password column Heading and fields** by default in all rows and show it on Edit for a particular row and have it also for Adding new row. I used the property **hidden: true** but I am unable to show it for a particular row I am editing only, maybe I could also display it with just stars like: -

```
Password
********
```

But I am unable to do so. Here's my code below so far:-

```
const [columns, setColumns] = useState<any>([
    {
      title: "Username",
      field: "username",
      draggable: false,
      cellStyle: { textAlign: "left" },
    },
    {
       title: "Password",
       field: "password",
       hidden: true,
       draggable: false,
       cellStyle: { textAlign: "left" },
    },
```

I would like to show it only for specific row I am editing and also on new row being added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define `editComponent` and `render` props on the password column definition, likes this:

```
  const tableColumns = [
   // ..other columns
  {
    title: "Password",
    field: "password",
    editComponent: ({ value, onChange }) => (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={value || ""}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
      />
    ),

    render: (rowData) => (
      <input
        type="password"
        value={rowData.password}
        readOnly />
    )
  }
];
```

This way the field won't be hidden but the passwords will only be shown during update or creation. Link to working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-editable-password-field-8pnny?file=/src/App.js).

[image: edit_password_field]